# Why bodyparser.json is parsing multipart/formdata?

Tags: node.js, parsing, express, multipartform-data

I'm trying to parse multipart/from-data with multer middleware. This is my post request:

```
POST /api/files HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f55caef0-1d59-fe80-f6ae-00e38fcbc92a

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="guia1"; filename="guia_1_MC_2012_2c.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

This is my app.js code:

```
var express    = require('express');        
var app        = express();                    
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var validator = require('express-validator'); 
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(multer({ dest: './files/'}));
app.use(validator());
```

When I do this I get the following error (now Updated):

```
Error: invalid json 
at parse (.../node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:72:15) 
at .../node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:98:18 
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (.../node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:136:7) 
at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16) 
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17) 
at _stream_readable.js:920:16 
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

So it seems that bodyParser.json() is parsing the data, when it shouldn't.

Comment: What version of `body-parser` are you using? Those line numbers don't match the current branch or any recent one I can see. Perhaps try upgrading?

Comment: Tryed updating to bodyParser version 1.10.0 but still getting error. Thanks loganfsmyth!

Comment: How are you getting that request body output? You'll need to do some debugging to see what data you're getting. I'd add a middleware function before the bodyparser line and dump the request body to the console to verify.

Comment: As per *express-validator* [docs](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), app.use(validator()) must be defined after app.use(express.bodyParser()). Just a note.

Answer (score 12):

Just found out that body-parser is working fine!! The thing was that postman was setting the content-type to application/json when submitting multipart/form-data, by default and also hiding the Header. Thanks loganfsmyth!!